# Microsoft Azure Backup - Where are the Logs?

Tags: backup, azure, windows-server-backup

We are using Microsoft Azure Backup to backup our server. Our backup is passing on 4 out of 5 drives, but consistently failing on the one. All that the Microsoft Azure GUI agent tells me though is that it failed. Where can I find the logs to further diagnose this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the cloudbackup\operational event log on the client.  Additional logs are in C:\program files\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\Temp.  In that directory take a look at CBEngineCurr.errlog, which should contain the step by step details on issues.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how does one view the cloudbackup\operational event log on the client?

Comment: eventvwr, then look in application and services logs, cloudbackup folder

Comment: @JimB I have a similar [question (here)](http://serverfault.com/questions/715996/microsoft-azure-backup-which-files-are-being-backed-up-logs)

Answer (score 2):

Another way you view the Microsoft Azure Backup Agent logs is accessing.
Server Manager > Diagnostics > Event Viewer > Application and services log > CloudBackup > Operational.
You will have a record of logs for the service