# Microsoft Azure Backup - which files are being backed up - logs

Tags: backup, azure, windows-10

There is a similar Q ([Microsoft Azure Backup - Where are the Logs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/696889/microsoft-azure-backup-where-are-the-logs) - but pertains to errors only). That directory is correct but doesn't contain anything else.

So my question is actually about the log (for the latest job) showing something like files/directories that were actually backed up (and I'm mostly concerned about incremental backups, seeing the differences being picked up so I could analyze that, adjust etc.)
Thanks!

P.S. Also this is the Windows client version backup not the server one (so there may be difference, agent seems different)