# Azure backup event logs

Tags: backup, azure

Does Azure backups for a virtual machine create event logs? A couple of days go we had a backup failure on one of the VM's but I could not find a single entry in the server's event logs.

Comment: Duplicate? https://serverfault.com/questions/696889/microsoft-azure-backup-where-are-the-logs

Answer (score 0):

Go to Server Manager > Diagnostics > Event Viewer > Application and services log > CloudBackup > Operational